# Set transient with get posts error

Tags: transient

I have a big WordPress installation more than 200K posts, with auto publish posts features. My post content is contained "some HTML tags, some text, some `<img>` tags". I need to remove all `<img>` tags from post content from the specific posts. So I have this function to do this job:

```
function remove_images_form_past_posts() {
    if ( get_transient('images_removed_from_past') )
        return;
    $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'post', 
                'year' => 2013, 
                'monthnum' => 1, 
                'day' =>28,     
                'post_status' =>'publish',
                'category' => 30,
                'post_author' => 3,
                'nopaging' => 1
            );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );    
        if ( $posts ) {
            foreach ( $posts as $post ); setup_postdata( $post ); {
                $newcontent = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '', $post->post_content);
                $newpost = array(
                               'ID' => $post->ID, 
                               'post_content' => $newcontent
                           );
                wp_update_post($newpost);
                wp_reset_postdata();
            }
            set_transient('images_removed_from_past', 60 * 60 * 24);
        }
    }
add_action('admin_init','remove_images_form_past_posts');
```

The code above is perfect & do the job but have one problem: this code is unfortunately update 1 post only although the `$args` is matching 9 posts.

I have tested the `get_posts` alone & it is working perfectly & executing 9 posts. I have stopped the `WP_super_cache` plugin & also no way. I have tried to change "set_transient $value from 1 to 9 with no way.

Any ideas!

Comment: Where does the variable `$images_removed_from_past` come from?

Comment: please see the first line of the code, came from the sqme function

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: ok, iam here because iam not a developer, not a wordpress expert, so please if you see any mistakes in the code tell me the true , i explained my goal & specified every thing, help me please by posting an answer for my question not by posting a new question

Comment: Believe it or not, to help you is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: thanks for this, to know the answer of your question please see the wordpress codex "set_transient"

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_transient

Comment: please remember that as i mentioned above every thing is worked percectly but for only 1 post not all posts... ok you are true but in the fact the first time i tested the function tested it without this.. so i will pdate the q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is for this function to run once a day and loop through all matching posts (removing `img` tags), I think this should do the trick:

```
<?php
function remove_images_form_past_posts() {
        if ( get_transient('images_removed_from_past') )
            return;
        $args = array( 
                    'post_type' => 'post', 
                    'year' => 2013, 
                    'monthnum' => 1, 
                    'day' =>28,     
                    'post_status' =>'publish',
                    'category' => 30,
                    'post_author' => 3,
                    'nopaging' => 1
                );
        $posts = get_posts( $args );    
            if ( $posts ) {
                foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
                    $newcontent = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '', $post->post_content);
                    $newpost = array(
                                   'ID' => $post->ID, 
                                   'post_content' => $newcontent
                               );
                    wp_update_post($newpost);
                }
                set_transient('images_removed_from_past',true, 60 * 60 * 24);
            }
        }
add_action('admin_init','remove_images_form_past_posts');
```

Comment: Isn't that just about what I suggested.. :D I wouldn't `wp_reset _postdata()` on every loop though. And @adnan the `set_transient()` is still kind of useless, because now it's set with the seconds for day as value and expiration set to 0, which means it won't expire. BTW when you are testing be sure that the transient isn't set, otherwise the piece of code you want to test won't execute. Just to clear that too.

Comment: setup_postdata( $post ); must be available see this please
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Access_all_post_data

Comment: @ialocin it's pretty darn close to what you suggested. His use of set_transient is *very* confusing to me as well, I actually meant to change that `set_transient()` call. Will make an edit now. And @adnan, `setup_postdata` really just allows you to use template tags, and you're not using them. If you `var_dump($post)` before you set $newcontent you'll see that what you need is available.

Comment: No, read again, it's really just needed if you want to use  template tags like `the_content()`.

Comment: ok, i have excuted delete_transient to clear it, changed the function & transient name, tested it

Comment: @murdaugh this code is worked perfectly for all matching posts. thanks for your help... one question please if i will ecxcute this function for 1000 post what is the transient value i can set?

Comment: The transient you're setting there just prevents this code from running more than once a day... So as long as the operation doesn't take all day for 1000 posts, I don't see why it would need to change. Does this really need to run every day though?

Comment: no, not every day i will create more than 100 function every one matching about 1 thousand post by &args to avoid server slowdown, only 1 thousand post

Comment: If you'll just be running this manually a few times during a migration period or something, I'd do away with the transients altogether. They really serve no purpose (besides causing extra headaches) unless this code will be run on a regular basis.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand

Comment: What was your reason for adding the `get_transient` and `set_transient` function calls to begin with? If I understand how you're using this, they aren't necessary.

Comment: the reason is because i have alot of posts & i don't need to make a load on the server decreasing it's performance.

Comment: And my point is that the way you're using get/set transient function calls here, you're not going to save on server load. For each run of this script, it's going to run through the entire set of entries all at once. On the other hand, if you were writing a script to run a function that only needed to run once a day or so, this would be the way to do it.

Comment: ok, so your suggestion is commpletly not using transient, it is good & i thinked about it, also what about if i used it what is your suggestion in this $value?

Comment: the way you're using it `$value` needs to be `true`. `$expiration` is going to be how long you want to wait before this code will run again (60*60*24 = 24 hours).

Comment: sorry i meant expiration, by your last comment your are helped me for the second time you understood it perfectly, thanks one more time, sorry for my poor english

Comment: @murdaugh a strange problem occured some posts after update returned with a strange content like this"Ø£Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ Ø§ÙÙØ§Ø" .. without replacing the image i think that happened because i have applie it to alot of posts.. what is your opinion?

Comment: Try altering your code to just apply to one of those problem posts at a time. I'd be more inclined to say that the problem is related to content in the post than some sort of overload in php.

Comment: when i tried to to apply to a strange post contents the img is replaced but the content is still strange characters, i have backuped my database before so now no problem, but what about to avoid this in future excuting?

Comment: i think you are right, now i test the code for the posts > 200K & i will let him about 40 hours & i will see the results

Comment: you are right about this u have edited yet now about 1k posts no problem with all of this, but i have another problem when i tried to matched more than 150 post the operation is failed & admin panel tajed along time loading & in the end of loading is is not opened & the replace not working.. any idea !

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your `foreach`-loop is wrong, you are breaking it by putting a `;` behind it. This is the reason why you only update one post. Just do it like this:

```
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) { //remove the »;«
            setup_postdata( $post ); //move this inside the loop
            $newcontent = preg_replace('#(<[/]?img.*>)#U', '', $post->post_content);
            $newpost = array(
                           'ID' => $post->ID, 
                           'post_content' => $newcontent
                       );
            wp_update_post($newpost);
        }
        wp_reset_postdata(); //do not forget to reset postdata after the loop
```

I changed the regex too, might not be absolutely necessary, but this one is working pretty good for me.

Additionally add:

```
global $post;
```

at the begin of your function. You don't have to do it see @murdaugh comment, but if you setup and reset postdata correct there is no harm. In fact there are some cases you have to do it, but that's not pertinent here. I just suggested it for failsafe reasons.

---

**Disclaimer:**
This second part isn't part of the answer to the question. It's just an extended consideration of the raised problem.

---

**Other notes:**

- I'm guessing you want your transient to reflect which posts are already cleaned up. Which makes absolutely sense if you are having 200k posts. In this case you should make sure your transient name is reflecting which set of post you already cleaned up. A generic one like in your function won't cut it. The transient name should reflect all the changing parameters of your `$args`. A stripped-down code snippet:

  ```
      //make your parameters variables
      $ay = '2013'; //year
      $am = '1'; //month
      $ad = '28'; //day
      $ac = '30'; //category
      $aa = '3'; //author

      //get your transient based on the set of variables
      if (get_transient('rm_img_'.$ay.'_'.$am.'_'.$ad.'_'.$ac.'_'.$aa.'') )
          return;

      //use the variables in your args
      $args = array( 
          'post_type' => 'post', 
          'year' => $ay, 
          'monthnum' => $am, 
          'day' => $ad,     
          'post_status' =>'publish',
          'category' => $ac,
          'post_author' => $aa,
          'nopaging' => 1
      );

      //get your transient based on the set of variables
      set_transient('rm_img_'.$ay.'_'.$am.'_'.$ad.'_'.$ac.'_'.$aa.'', true, 0);
  ```
- *This isn't working as it is!* Just to make that very clear.
- It's just an idea on how to make use of the transient, for you or anybody else interested.
- Of course there are some other steps, for example:

  - What you probably really want is that the function takes those parameters as arguments.
  - Besides that one would probably want way more possibilities for automated looping an iterating.

Ok, I'm going to break this here, before it's getting out of hand.

Comment: ok i will update the q with last one i have used & please see it

Comment: unfortunately after moved setup_postdata( $post ); inside loop.. no way

Comment: global $post; add this after the line function remove_images_form_past_posts() { ... also no way

Comment: I agree that the structure foreach loop is an issue, but because he's populating $post with the contents of the $posts object in that foreach loop, there's no reason to add `global $post;` anywhere. That really could just foul things up. One could also argue that he shouldn't be using `$post` as a variable name because it causes readability issues.

Comment: @murdaugh please post a complete code to test it

Comment: @ialocin sorry man but iam not clever in english language

Comment: Ok, I'm taking a few guesses here because I don't understand all of your goals completely, but the answer I just committed should behave predictably, at least.

Comment: @ialocin thank you very much for your help & iam sorry for my poor english.
please note: my regex code is good i tested it more than 10 times you can test any regex here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: but i have 1 question please if i will ecxcute this function for 1000 post what is the transient value i can set?